# What to do about 'data truncated for column' warnings on csv import?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to import data from a text file into table in mysql-5.5. Here is the table create code:

```
CREATE TABLE `price` (
`symbol` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`date` DATE NOT NULL,
`open` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`high` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`low` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`close` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`volume` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`date`, `symbol`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Here is the import code.

```
INFILE 'c:/temp/DTB3.csv'
INTO TABLE price 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(symbol, date, @dummy, @dummy, close);
```

Here are some rows of data.

```
10,2019-01-30,1.00,1.00,50459.4301
10,2019-01-31,1.00,1.00,50477.9307
10,2019-02-01,1.00,1.00,50496.4382
```

Here is a sample warning:

```
Warning 1,265 Data truncated for column 'close' at row 12
```

The data in the resulting table looks correct.

[image]

I have tried both double and float for the price fields.

Why am I getting these warnings and what can I do about them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles across this problem amending the query to add:
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
stopped the warnings. Apparently MySQL was trying to append the carriage return to the close field on import.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you have declared 7 columns in your table but giving data for only 5.

Try adding commas for the missing (null) fields in your import data so the import knows explicitly there's no value to load.

Like this:

```
10,2019-01-30,1.00,1.00,50459.4301,,
10,2019-01-30,1.00,1.00,50459.4301,,
10,2019-01-30,1.00,1.00,50459.4301,,
```

Comment: Adding as couple of blank fields (commas) had no effect on the warnings or the results.

Comment: Actually the warning message changed when the two commas were appended: Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns